# Including file with try and catch function

Tags: php

```
<?php
    function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) 
    {
       throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
    }
       set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");

   try {
      //include 'http://www.svrsstatus.com/banner.html';  
      //include 'http://www.svrsstatus.com/banner_outage_sample.html';  
   } 
   catch (ErrorException $ex) {
       /* echo "Unable to load configuration file.";  */
       include 'http://staging.sorenson.com/test.html';
   }  
?>
```

I'm trying to test the catch function to display the test.html file if the include in the try function is not available. I tested and it didn't show anything. Did I write this code in the wrong way?

Thanks for your wisdom!

Comment: Use `require` instead of include, [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) vs [require](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)

Comment: Is it because you commented out your includes?

Comment: What @DirkScholten says, works fine https://3v4l.org/RjPqF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the function [`file_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) for handling the file availability, not a `try ... catch` block.

```php
<?php
if (file_exists("filename.php"))
  include "filename.php";
else
  include "404.php";
?>
```

Also please note that, for including web URLs, you might need to have the following set `allow_url_fopen` directive.

Comment: `include (file_exists('file.php') ? 'file.php' : '404.php');` - just to oneliner it ;)

Comment: @treyBake Awesome!  Haven't tried ternary there coz I have been using it as a keyword, but wow. Thanks.

Comment: Yee, I think I've literally just started using ternary in these places, feels nice to do :)

Comment: They implemented an error handler to throw exceptions and it works fine https://3v4l.org/RjPqF

Comment: @AbraCadaver I saw your comment in the question. Maybe you can take as an alternate suggestion or solution.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with OP code except they commented out the code that causes an error so there is no error and no exception to catch.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Ah okay!

Comment: Thank you guys! I like the idea if the file does not exist it switch to the existing file. This is why I commented out the include to test it and yes I need the `allow_url_fopen`. Where do I put this in the code?

Comment: @ChristianLuneborg It has to be enabled in the `php.ini`. 

Comment: Where do I find that? Im no expert in PHP.

Comment: Google Search and random result: [How to Find the Location of Your php.ini File](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/phpini-file/)

Comment: Ok, Ill look it up, but your code above is giving me an error message.

Comment: @ChristianLuneborg I forgot to add one more `)`. Sorry. Corrected it now.

Comment: Your code works like charm! Thank you! It doesnt need the `allow_url_fopen` - whew!